# strtotime & date validation (01/20/2011 vs 01/2011)

Tags: php, regex, strtotime

```
01/20/2011 = January 20, 2011

01/2011 = January 2011
```

Only these two formats should be allowed!

```
i.e. 01/01/01/2011 = ERROR!
```

PHP:

```
$date = '01/20/2011';

//$date = '01/2011';

if(........format test........)//01/20/2011
{
    if(...validation...)
    {
        echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($date));
    }
}
else//01/2011
{
    if(...validation...)
    {
        echo date('F Y', .....);
    }
}
```

*Validation:*

**IF = 01/20/2011**

- First part should only contain numbers 01-12
- Second part should only contain numbers 01-31
- Third part should consist of 4 numbers

**IF = 01/2011**

- First part should only contain numbers 01-12
- Second part should consist of 4 numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work:

```
function custom_checkdate($date){
    $date_parts = explode('/', $date);

    if(count($date_parts) === 3){
        $d = $date_parts[1];
        $m = $date_parts[0];
        $y = $date_parts[2];
    }elseif(count($date_parts) === 2){
        $d = 1;
        $m = $date_parts[0];
        $y = $date_parts[1];
    }else{
        return false;
    }

    if( checkdate($m, $d, $y) ){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```